# value based conditional selection in pandas throwing ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select rows from a pandas dataframe based on some condition on one column.
Let's day, my dataframe columns are: user, age, gender.
I am trying to figure out rows with user value 'kunal'. I tried two following ways:

```
df.loc[df.user == 'kunal']
df.loc[df.user == 'kunal', :]
```

It's throwing the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

I don't know if pandas has changed anything in the latest version.

Comment: Whats the actual data?

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe problem is `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['kunal',''],'b':[1,2]})
df.columns = [['user'] * 2, df.columns]
print(df)
    user   
       a  b
0  kunal  1
1         2

print(df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['user'], ['a', 'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]])
```

Possible solution is select by tuples:

```
df3 = df.loc[df.loc[:, ('user','a')] == 'kunal']
print(df3)

    user   
       a  b
0  kunal  1
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping me out. I was actually renaming columns in a way that was leading to Multiindex in columns.